# How to search for intervals in Java

Tags: java, arrays, search, find

Just before I begin to annoy you, I am a Java beginner and my main issue up to date is two- ord more-dimensional arrays. 
Let me represent my problem: 
The task in the study was: you have an sorted array, then you type the number of how many searching operations(let them named by `N`) the Programm should do. 
Due to this you type `N x 2` different values `a` and `b`, `a` should be smaller than `b`. 
The Programm should search in the sorted array for intervalls containing your `a` and `b` and print these intervalls out. 
For example: 
The array to search for looks like this:

```
 [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

then the user types in the number of operations, for example 3. Following to this the `a` and `b` couples:

```
3 6 

2 9

1 5
```

The output of the programm should be according to these `a`  and `b` couples:

```
3 7

1 9

1 5
```

I tried to master this exercise but as mentioned above I have problems with multidimensional arrays. At the following you can see my code and I just want tipps or specific informations about arrays to understand how they're working. 
And i improved it:

```
import java.util.*; 
public class Blatt9{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); 
        boolean check1 = false; 
        int N = s.nextInt(); 
        int[] array = new int[N]; 
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            array[i] = s.nextInt(); 
        }       
        for(int j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
            for(int k = j+1; j < array.length -1; j++){
                if(array[j] < array[k]){
                    check1 = true;                   
                }
                else{
                    check1 = false;     
                }           
            }
        }
        if(check1){
            System.out.println("nicht aufsteigend sortiert"); 
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("korrekt"); 
        }

        //Beginn der eigentlichen Aufgabe
        int abfragen = s.nextInt();       // Anzahl der Abfragen
        int[][] arr = new int[abfragen][2];  //um die abfragen zu speichern
        int a = 0; 
        int b = 0; 
        for(int i = 0; i < abfragen; i++){
            a = s.nextInt();  
            b = s.nextInt(); 
            if(a>b){
                System.out.println("Zahl 1 muss kleiner Zahl 2 sein"); 
                break; 
            }
            arr[i][0] = a; 
            arr[i][1] = b; 
        }
        int intervall1 = 0; 
        int intervall2 = 0; 

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
                if(array[i] <= a){
                    intervall1 = a; 
                    }
                    if(array[i]>= b){
                        intervall2 = b; 
                    }
                }
            System.out.print(intervall1 + " " + intervall2); 
            System.out.println(); 
        }

    }
}
```

The output now is:

input:

```
5

1 3 5 7 9
```

korrekt

```
3

3 6

2 9

1 5
```

begin of output:

```
1 0

1 0

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5

1 5
```

Comment: Maybe you should also provide what is the output of oyur code right now!

Comment: I did it now :D